# Create android widgets in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there any way or library how to create android pinnable widget to the desktop (as for example time) in flutter? Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Svk7xmscKk , video by flutter team member

Comment: @AmanVerma he is not normal.